# How to replace data in a NSARRAY where the value and key equal?

Tags: objective-c

i'm inserting text field data on textFieldDidEndEditing, into an array.

but i don't want duplicates. if user changes the textfield data, i want it to be replaced by the new and updated in the dictionary that has the key name "product" with value of "bagel".

**.h**

```
@interface Bread_TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{


    NSMutableArray *productarray;


}
```

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    productarray = [NSMutableArray array];

}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Make sure to set the label to have a ta
    NSString*textfieldclicked;

    if (textField.tag == 1) {
        textfieldclicked=@"Unit";
    } else if (textField.tag ==2) {
        textfieldclicked=@"Case";

    }

    id textFieldSuper = textField;

    while (![textFieldSuper isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {

        textFieldSuper = [textFieldSuper superview];

    }
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)textFieldSuper];

    InventoryTableViewCell *cell = (InventoryTableViewCell *)[self.tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:textField.text,textfieldclicked,cell.product.text,@"product",nil];


    [productarray addObject:plainPart];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this maybe :

```
    //the KEY exist
    if ([productarray valueForKeyPath:YOUR_KEY]) {
       //test if value doesn't exist for this key
       if (![[productarray valueForKeyPath:YOUR_KEY] containsObject:YOUR_VALUE]) {
          NSDictionary *oldPart = [[productarray valueForKeyPath:YOUR_KEY] firstObject];
          NSInteger index = [productArray indexOfObject:oldPart];
          [productarray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:plainPart];
       }

    }
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: index 2147483647 beyond bounds for empty array'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSMutableOrderedSet`, which works like an NSArray, but it guarantees uniqueness of elements.

You don't have to worry about implementing `-hash` and `-isEqual:` as you're using `NSString` and `NSDictionary` which already have them defined.